# Is there a way to read a .twbx file in R?

Tags: r, tableau-api

I am looking to import my tableau output file,.twbx, into R so that I can do some data manipulations.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible but I know there is a [Java API for Tableau Data Extract (TDE) files](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/sdk/en-us/help.htm) and [R supports Java ...](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rJava/index.html)

Comment: Tableau has an interface to R. Why not use that to send relevant data to R for the calculations Tableau can't do?

Comment: Not sure what interface you are talking about. Can you post some links?

Answer (score 1):

No, you should connect to the source data instead. `.twbx` contains your data but it also contains all of Tableau's graphics information, calculations, etc., and it's all encoded specifically for Tableau, not R (a Tableau data extract is not a generic data format). You can however copy and paste your data from Tableau into Excel and save it as `.csv` or `.xlsx`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your twbx to zip and get the twb file out of it. This twb file can be easily read in R and you can extract information from there using R functions.

Comment: Appreciated your efforts to help. If you can show a code example, your answer would help many and attracts attention.